# bootstrap combo dropdown buttons space issue

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, safari

I am using a bootstrap split button dropdown but i get an space between the button and the dropdown menu button. This problem only comes with the safari browser. It works fine with other browsers. I am using code from here:

[Bootstrap split dropdown menu](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#buttonDropdowns)

Even on the official website it breaks and have a space in the split button dropdown. This is a issue only with safari. Works fairly well in other browsers. I checked with 2-3 different installations of safari.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This bug has been reported allready, and it seems the stance is that safari for windows simply is not supported by bootstrap.

https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/5644

Furthermore this bug only seems to occur on windows version of safari.

If you can not live with this bug, try targeting safari, but make sure you test it on both win and mac, so you dont fix it on win but break it on mac.

Ways to target safari:

Adding an extra # will only be read by safari (very hacky)

```
##id {width:100px;}
```

How to target only Windows Agents with js:

```
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Mac")!=-1) {
} else {
    $('body').addClass('win');
}
```

This will add the class win to body, if the user uses windows.

After that you can target safari with css:

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {

    .win { height: 100%; }

}
```

The result is, you will be only targeting safari on windows.

After that you just need to adjust, whatever is causing the issue.

Most likely it is padding or margin on the button element, or maybe width. Try playing with these, if nothing else helps relative position or even a negative margin might help.

Relevant HTML from bootstrap:

```
<!-- /btn-group -->
              <div class="btn-group">
                <button class="btn btn-primary">Action</button>
                <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="caret"></span></button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div><!-- /btn-group -->
```

If you want to target dropdown menu use:

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {

    .win .dropdown-menu { height: 100%; }

}
```

Now you can hack away!

Or, simply dont support safari on windows :)

Comment: is it true that safari has been officially discontinued on windows?

Comment: dont know. what i know is that bootstrap wont support it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with using `@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0)` is that this targets Chrome browser as well.

I found a solution with using z-index positioning and this fix the problem on both Safari and Chrome browsers, and does not require any JavaScript or changes to HTML code:

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
.btn-group > .btn + .btn {
    margin-left: -5px;
}  
.btn-group:hover a {
    z-index:1;
}
.btn-group:hover button{
    z-index:10;
}
.input-append input{
    z-index:1;
}
.input-append  a{
    z-index:10;
}}
```